# Copy and paste worksheet from one to another

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have 2 different excel files as indicated below:

1. Report.csv
2. Report.Xlsm

Both Files has a worksheet name "Report"

I need a vba script to do this from MsAccess.

I need to copy the "Report" sheet from Report.csv and replace it with the "Report" sheet in Report.xlsm and save the xlsm file. 
Also, need to quit the application. The code below is doing the job except isn't replacing the "Report" sheet.

```
Private Sub CopyPaste()

Dim CopyFrom As Object
Dim CopyTo As Object ' Workbook
Dim CopyThis As Object
Dim xl As Object 'New Excel.Application


Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True


Set CopyFrom = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\desktop\report.csv")
Set CopyThis = CopyFrom.Sheets(1) ''Sheet number 1

Set CopyTo = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\users\me\desktop\Report.xlsm")
CopyThis.Copy After:=CopyTo.Sheets(CopyTo.Sheets.Count)

CopyFrom.Close True
CopyTo.Save
CopyTo.Close True
xl.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Paste this and see:

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim CopyFrom As Object
Dim CopyTo As Object ' Workbook
Dim CopyThis As Object
Dim xl As Object 'New Excel.Application


Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True


Set CopyFrom = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\desktop\report.csv")
Set CopyThis = CopyFrom.Sheets(1) ''Sheet number 1

Set CopyTo = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\users\me\desktop\Report.xlsm")

CopyThis.Copy After:=CopyTo.Sheets(CopyTo.Sheets.Count)

'Start of new code added
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
CopyTo.Sheets(1).Delete 'deletes the sheet that was initially there
xl.DisplayAlerts = True
CopyTo.Sheets(1).Name = "report" 'now the copied sheet has the index of 1
'End of new code added

CopyFrom.Close True
CopyTo.Save
CopyTo.Close True
xl.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: It is still hanging at "Application.DisplayAlerts = False". Just to let you know I am running this from an Access Vba.

Comment: Please use `xl.DisplayAlerts = False` and `xl.DisplayAlerts = False` as per updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Private Sub CopyPaste()

Dim CopyFrom As Object
Dim CopyTo As Object ' Workbook
Dim CopyThis As Object
Dim xl As Object 'New Excel.Application


Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True


Set CopyFrom = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\desktop\report.csv")
Set CopyThis = CopyFrom.Sheets("Report") ''Sheet number is ok if it never move, name may be safer

Set CopyTo = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\users\me\desktop\Report.xlsm")

xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
CopyTo.sheets("Report").Delete
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

CopyThis.Copy After:=CopyTo.Sheets(CopyTo.Sheets.Count)

CopyFrom.Close True
CopyTo.Save
CopyTo.Close True
xl.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Error "Method or data member not found " at "Application.DisplayAlerts = False"

Comment: Indeed, as it is in Access, you need to specify that the application is Excel! Take a look at the edit! ;)

Comment: The code will not work with the updated answer. You are trying to delete the only sheet in the workbook before copying the sheet. It will return runtime error 1004. A workbook must contain atleast one visible sheet

Comment: Not sure that there is only one sheet but indeed if that is the case, this won't work! Thx for mentionning it!